# HTML line break formatting in VS is not working?

Tags: html, visual-studio, code-formatting

I've adjusted my VS 2010 HTML formatting settings to do line breaks "Before opening, within, and after closing" for many tags such as the `<a>` and `<li>` tags.

But this only renders as the following when formatting the document:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 0</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 1</a></li>
    <li>
        ...
```

How can I make VS 2010 (or 2008) format the HMTL this way instead?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 0
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        ...
```

Comment: I don't know VS HTML, but maybe it treats <a> different to </a>. Can you manually add a rule for </a>?

Comment: No, Visual Studio doesn't work that way. The rules applies to tags (a, br, div etc.), not string fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer help? [Configuring the formatting of <% %> blocks in Visual Studio editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159683/configuring-the-formatting-of-blocks-in-visual-studio-editor)