# Visual Studio Code Html tag allignment

Tags: visual-studio-code

On line 14 to 17 p tags are wrapping the text from top and bottom but on line 18 p tag is wrap the text from right and left. I noticed that the length of line cause that but I can't find the setting of it. I want all tags are wrap the content from top and bottom like line 14 to 17. Which settings do I have to change.[image: The picture of IDE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way in Vscode:
File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Prettier -> find the tab width and change the 80 value to 1 or 2 in that case everything I write in tags are automatically placed in the top and bottom of the text between texts.
[image: Tab width example]

[image: Example of the result]

As seen in the picture tags are always on the top and bottom of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer helps:  ([Configuring the formatting of <% %> blocks in Visual Studio editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159683/configuring-the-formatting-of-blocks-in-visual-studio-editor))

Or check vscode html-formatter : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.